# Count based on a value from duplicate rows

Tags: excel, exception, excel-formula

Trying to figure out an excel formula to read the following table. I want to count of the status once. I want to count the amount of names that are "In progress" (the count should be two). My previous countif() formula gave me the count of 4.

```
Name    User    Device      Status
Name1   User1   Machine1    In progress
Name1   User1   Machine2    In progress
Name2   User2   Machine3    Passed
Name2   User2   Machine4    Passed
Name3   User4   Machine5    Passed
Name3   User4   Machine6    Passed
Name4   User4   Machine7    In progress
Name4   User4   Machine8    In progress
```

Comment: Maybe combine `COUNTIF` and `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($D$2:$D$9=F2,1/COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,$A$2:$A$9,$D$2:$D$9,F2)))
```

I put `In Progress` in F2

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]